# What are the disadvantages of using extended properties to tag columns with metadata?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am designing a project which has a goal to **tag SQL columns** with additional **key-value pair attributes**.

SQL Server's native **extended properties** seems to be a good solution to achieve this goal. In this case, we will not need to maintain our own set of tables and CRUD operations to manage the data since they're already available:

- Create: sp_addextendedproperty
- Update: sp_updateextendedproperty
- Delete: sp_dropextendedproperty
- View: fn_listextendedproperty or sys.extended_properties.

I'm just wondering: Are there any **disadvantages** in using extended properties?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure about the disadvantages of using them (having never heard of any!) but I did sit through an excellent session by James Skipwith on utilising them to enable the building and tagging of tables and other objects which may be of interest to you to help you implement or find out more about them: http://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event11/Table-Based_Database_Object_Factories

Comment: If they're a possibility that you'll move to Azure at any time, I'd avoid them since they're not supported there.

Comment: I have seen some tools lose them (SQL Compare, for example). Apart from that I have used them successfully.

Comment: @StephLocke, thanks for the recommendation. I'll check this!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I haven't heard any plans that we'll be moving to Azure in the short-term but thanks a lot for the heads up!